# webRTC just works when relaunching the server for the first time

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io, webrtc

I am trying to build a simple peer to peer connection, 1 to 1, where a user shares his video peer to peer and we end up watching our localStream and the remoteOne on both sides.

I started building the webrtc connection with agoraRTM (for the signaling part) and it worked fine. I tried to change the signaling to use socket.io instead of agoraRTM.

In the end the app has a weird behaviour (probably related to socketIO) where if I run the first time it works (first time after websocket server relaunch), then it just stops working.

Here is my code:

main.js (webRTC and client socket.io)

```
let token = null;
let uid = String(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000));

let queryString = window.location.search;
const urlSearch = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
const room = urlSearch.get("room");

if (!room) {
  window.location = "lobby.html";
}

let client;
let channel;
let socket;

const constraints = {
  video: {
    width: { min: 640, ideal: 1920, max: 1920 },
    height: { min: 480, ideal: 1080, max: 1920 },
    aspectRatio: 1.777777778,
  },
  audio: false,
};

const servers = {
  iceServers: [
    {
      urls: [
        "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302",
        "stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302",
        "stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302",
        "stun:stun3.l.google.com:19302",
        "stun:stun4.l.google.com:19302",
      ],
    },
  ],
};

const localVideoRef = document.getElementById("localVideo");
const remoteVideoRef = document.getElementById("remoteVideo");

let localStream;
let remoteStream;

let peerConnection;

const configureSignaling = async () => {
  socket = await io.connect("http://localhost:4000");

  socket.emit("join", { room, uid });
  socket.on("MemberJoined", handleMemberJoined);
  socket.on("MessageFromPeer", handleMessageFromPeer);

  socket.on("MemberLeft", handleMemberLeft)
};

const handleMemberLeft = async () => {
  remoteVideoRef.style.display = "none";
};

const handleMessageFromPeer = (m, uid) => {
  const message = JSON.parse(m.text);
  
  if(message.type !== "candidate") {
    console.log('handleMessageFromPeer: ', message, uid)
  }

  if (message.type === "offer") {
    createAnswer(uid, message.offer);
  }

  if (message.type === "answer") {
    addAnswer(message.answer);
  }

  if (message.type === "candidate") {
    if (peerConnection && peerConnection.currentRemoteDescription) {
      peerConnection.addIceCandidate(message.candidate);
    }
  }
};

const createLocalStream = async () => {
  localStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
  localVideoRef.srcObject = localStream;
};

const init = async () => {
  await configureSignaling();
  await createLocalStream();
};

const handleMemberJoined = async (uid) => {
  createOffer(uid);
};

let createOffer = async (uid) => {
  await createPeerConnection(uid);

  let offer = await peerConnection.createOffer();
  await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);

  socket.emit(
    "sendMessageToPeer",
    { text: JSON.stringify({ type: "offer", offer: offer }) },
    uid
  );
};

let createPeerConnection = async (uid) => {
  peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);

  remoteStream = new MediaStream();
  remoteVideoRef.srcObject = remoteStream;
  remoteVideoRef.style.display = "block";
  remoteVideoRef.classList.add("remoteFrame");

  if (!localStream) {
    await createLocalStream();
  }

  localStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
    peerConnection.addTrack(track, localStream);
  });

  peerConnection.ontrack = (event) => {
    event.streams[0].getTracks().forEach((track) => {
      remoteStream.addTrack(track);
    });
  };

  peerConnection.onicecandidate = (event) => {
    if (event.candidate) {
      socket.emit(
        "sendMessageToPeer",
        {
          text: JSON.stringify({
            type: "candidate",
            candidate: event.candidate,
          }),
        },
        uid
      );
    }
  };
};

let createAnswer = async (uid, offer) => {
  await createPeerConnection(uid);
  await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(offer);
  
  const answer = await peerConnection.createAnswer();
  await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer);
  
  socket.emit(
    "sendMessageToPeer",
    { text: JSON.stringify({ type: "answer", answer: answer }) },
    uid
  );
};

let addAnswer = async (answer) => {
  if (!peerConnection.currentRemoteDescription) {
    peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(answer);
  }
};

let onLogout = async () => {
  remoteVideoRef.classList.remove("remoteFrame");
  await socket.emit('onLeaveRoom', room)
};

let onToggleCamera = async () => {
  const videoTrack = localStream
    .getTracks()
    .find((track) => track.kind === "video");
  if (videoTrack.enabled) {
    videoTrack.enabled = false;
    document.getElementById("camera-btn").style.backgroundColor =
      "rgb(255, 80, 80)";
  } else {
    videoTrack.enabled = true;
    document.getElementById("camera-btn").style.backgroundColor =
      "rgb(179, 102, 249, .9)";
  }
};

let onToggleMic = async () => {
  const audioTrack = localStream
    .getTracks()
    .find((track) => track.kind === "audio");
  if (audioTrack.enabled) {
    audioTrack.enabled = false;
    document.getElementById("mic-btn").style.backgroundColor =
      "rgb(255, 80, 80)";
  } else {
    audioTrack.enabled = true;
    document.getElementById("mic-btn").style.backgroundColor =
      "rgb(179, 102, 249, .9)";
  }
};

window.addEventListener("beforeunload", onLogout);

init();
```

index.js (websocket server)

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const PORT = 4000;

const http = require("http").Server(app);
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());

const socketIO = require("socket.io")(http, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://127.0.0.1:5501",
  },
});

//Add this before the app.get() block
socketIO.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log(`⚡: ${socket.id} user just connected!`);
  console.log('CONNECTED')

  socket.on('join', async ({room, uid}) => {
    await socket.join(room);

    const connectedUsers = await socket.in(room).fetchSockets()

    console.log('room:', connectedUsers.length);

    if(connectedUsers.length) {
      console.log('PUMBA')
      socket.broadcast.emit('MemberJoined', uid)
    }
  })

  socket.on("onLeaveRoom", async (room) => {
    await socket.leave(room)
    socket.broadcast.emit('MemberLeft')
  })

  socket.on("disconnect", async (room) => {
    socket.broadcast.emit('MemberLeft')
  })

  socket.on('sendMessageToPeer', (data, uid) => {
    console.log('sendMessageTOPEER', uid)
    socket.broadcast.emit('MessageFromPeer', data, uid ) 
  });
});

app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    message: "Hello world",
  });
});

http.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on ${PORT}`);
});
```

I tried a couple of different things, like checking how many users are in the room, the specific websocket ids, if the sdp offer and answer are being sent after I connect a new user (this is working correctly), not sure what is failling, any help? Thanks!